# what server role is more demanding?

Tags: database, application

There's about 125 simultaneous users connecting by a mapped drive to server A hosting an application that each user is running. This application on server A is getting its data from an Oracle server on server B. The database is about 5GB and there's fairly heavy reading and moderate updating of data.

Is this enough information for some basic specs for each server? If not, which server will have the most demand placed on it?

Comment: You haven't even specified the architecture or OS of Servers A and B. Or what the application is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say from what you give us, because there are too many variables.

I.e. the database queries could be very simple while the application needs large amounts of RAM and/or disk IO to do it's work, or, the other way round, the app is extremely simple but queries the database with a large amount of highly complex queries. Depending on this, the answer would be very different.

Comment: The queries are long and complex with several joins but it's a powerbuilder application so it's pretty heavy. Both boxes will have windows server 2008 if that matters. That's really all I know about them. I'll just have them shoot the moon for both :-)